# Configurar Jenkins para gerar build a cada commit?

Tags: java, jenkins

Eu tenho o Jenkins instalado corretamente e gerando build a cada 30 minutos, porem eu gostaria de gerar build a cada commit no repositório svn.

Tentei configurar a opção: Consultar periodicamente o SCM, mas não tive sucesso.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Com o que exatamente você não teve sucesso? Deu algum erro?

Comment: Não da nenhum erro e não começa gerar release.

Comment: E quantos commits vocês fez desde que configurou o hudson?

Comment: Isso pode ter alguma diferença? Já faz mais de 10 dias que está rodando com geração de build de tempo em tempo. E já foi muitos commits.

Comment: E quis dizer depois que você mudou para "Consultar periodicamente o SCM". Já commitou algo desde então?

Comment: Sim, vários commits.

Comment: Não sei se você tentou alguma coisa ou procurou no SO em inglês. Tem isso lá: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014252/jenkins-ci-how-to-trigger-builds-on-svn-commit. Se for isso, alguém pode traduzir a resposta de lá.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recomendo você utilizar um 'Post-commit hook', onde a cada commit o servidor do SVN notifica o Jenkins, através de uma URL e dispara o build. Desta forma você evita o overhead, caso a periodicidade de consulta seja baixa ou possua muitos projetos.

Exemplos e tutoriais:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin
http://imasters.com.br/artigo/16631/desenvolvimento/customizando-o-subversion/

Answer (score 0):

Veja aqui como está o meu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurei para consultar o repositório a cada 5 minutos.